# Issue while submitting a form in mvc application with reverse proxy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reverse-proxy

I am facing a weird issue related to reverse proxy in IIS
we have two web sites one public facing and an internal training website.
The requirement is that when an end user access the public website suffixed with /training he should be redirected to the internal training
website without changing the url. I have set both inbound and outbound rules .
The issue is that the training website contains a login page. When the request is "GET" the login page is displayed accordingly but after
submitting the login form (MVC .net application HTTPPOST) the post action is never called and a blank page appears with the same url.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have post controller action for Login.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
      //this calls once form posted
    }

    //this is for displaying
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks ashwini,Both the methods are there but my question is not actually about mvc post. The issue is with reverse proxy in IIS which uses ARR and rewrite rule.